# ¿Cómo iterar en los elementos de un archivo json?

Tags: javascript, json, dialogflow

Tengo un chatbot DialogFlow donde creo tarjetas con preguntas y respuestas. Las escribí a mano. Sin embargo, tengo esta lista como una pregunta en un archivo json. ¿Cómo puedo acceder a las preguntas y respuestas de mi expediente en lugar de escribirlas a mano? ¿Hay alguna forma de automatizar?

Aquí está el código del editor en línea para mi chatbot

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion, Payload} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var answers = [];
var score = {};


process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function answerIntroductionHandler(agent){
    agent.add(new Card({
        title: '1 Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?', # pregunta 1
        imageUrl: 'http://www.leparisien.fr/resizer/mz-PnB5RECZ1q-z9GDRvlB_3jsg=/932x582/arc-anglerfish-eu-central-1-prod-leparisien.s3.amazonaws.com/public/RJPSM346RO4M5VIDDOS35APBII.jpg'
      })
    );
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Oui"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Non"));
  }

  function answer1Handler(agent){

    const answer = agent.parameters.Boolean;
    answers.push(answer);

    agent.add(new Card({
        title: '2 Faut-il faire payer le stationnement des deux-roues ?', # pregunta 2
        imageUrl: 'https://img.autoplus.fr/news/2017/06/28/1517769/c4d017960fb061c5e50cf2c4-1350-900.jpg?r'
      })
    );
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Oui"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Non"));

  }

  function answer2Handler(agent){
    const answer = agent.parameters.Boolean;
    answers.push(answer);

  }


  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('answerIntroduction', answerIntroductionHandler);
  intentMap.set('answer1', answer1Handler);
  intentMap.set('answer2', answer2Handler);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Aqui esta mi archivo json de preguntas y respuestas:

```
{
    "Transports": {
        "Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il faire payer le stationnement des deux-roues ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il interdire les bus de tourisme dans la capitale ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il piétonniser les quatre arrondissements centraux de la capitale ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il réduire le nombre de places de stationnement en surface ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il rendre le Vélib' gratuit ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il renforcer la vidéoverbalisation ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il rouvrir à la circulation les voies sur berges ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il interdire les trottinettes électriques ? (free floating)": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Le périphérique doit-il...": [
            "... être supprimé",
            "... comprendre une voie pour bus et covoiturage",
            "... être préservé"
        ],
        "Les transports doivent-ils être rendus gratuits...": [
            "... uniquement pour les seniors",
            "... pour les mineurs et les seniors",
            "... pour tout le monde",
            "Non, ils doivent rester payants"
        ]
    },
    "Sports et Loisirs": {
        "Faut-il demander l'annulation des Jeux olympiques ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il mettre fin à la pratique du tirage au sort pour le conservatoire ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) para recorrer el objeto como si fuera "un *array*".

```
const loopThrough = (callback, object) => {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        callback(key, object[key]);
    });
}
```

Esta función recorrerá todas las *properties* del objeto y llamará a la *callback* por argumento pasando tanto la *key* como el *value*.

De esa forma, puedes recorrer los diferentes objetos de tu *json*

```
loopThrough((question, answers) => {
    console.log(question);
    console.log(answers);

    const card = new Card({
        title: question,
        imageUrl: //...
    });

    // etc...
    const suggestions = answers.map(a => new Suggestion(a));
}, data.Transports);
```

Y aquí estoy dando por supuesto que los temas (*Sports et Loisirs*, *Transports*, ...) es algo que quieres acceder manualmente, pero también se podría automatizar

```
const handleQuestion = (question, answers) => {
    console.log(question);
    console.log(answers);
}

loopThrough((topic, questions) => {
    loopThrough(handleQuestion, questions);
}, data);
```

---

**EDIT** Crear la entrada al `Map` para cada pregunta

Puedes modificar la función `loopThrough` para que también provea el índice a la *callback*

```
const loopThrough = (callback, object) => {
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key, i) => {
        callback(key, object[key], i);
    });
}
```

De esta forma podemos crear entradas dinámicas al `Map`.

```
// Ahora handleQuestion también recibirá el índice i
const handleQuestion = (question, answers, i) => {
    const handler = agent => {
        agent.add(new Card({...})); // Añade la card basada en el titulo (question)
        answers.forEach(agent.addans); // Añade cada una de las respuestas
    }

    // Añadimos la función en el map
    // con la key basada en el indice
    intentMap.set(`answer${i}`, handler);
}
```

Ahora, si vas a iterar sobre tus diferentes *topic*, el indice se va a repetir porque empezará de cero para cada *topic*. Para ello, podemos aprovechar el cambio en `loopThrough` para sacar también el índice de los *topic* y pasarlo a la función `handleQuestion`.

```
// el argumento topic es el indice del topic
// el argumento i es el indice de la pregunta.
const handleQuestion = (topic, question, answers, i) => {
    const handler = agent => {
        // ...
    }

    // Creamos la key del Map basado en ambos indices
    // De modo que será único
    intentMap.set(`answer${topic}${i}`, handler);
}


loopThrough((topic, questions, i) => {
    // Creamos la función con el índice indexado
    // El arg this será nulo porque no lo 
    // usamos en ningún momento
    const indexedHandler = handleQuestion.bind(null, i);
    loopThrough(indexedHandler, questions);
}, data);
```

Y, como decía en los comentarios, no sé absolutamente nada acerca de la librería *dialog flow*, por lo que poco puedo ayudar con todo aquello relacionado con el `agent` o las `Card`, etc...
Pero creo que con esta abstracción puedes llegar a una buena implementación.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: ¡Gracias por su idea! Con lo que amablemente me das puedo obtener todas las preguntas y respuestas, incluso los temas. Pero, como tengo que crear una función del estilo de Intent1Handler para cada pregunta que hago, y colocar la tarjeta que contiene la pregunta y la respuesta, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias de nuevo por su respuesta tan educativa y siento molestarle.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la función `intent1Handler`? De todas formas, lamento comentar que no conozco esta librería que estas usando, `dialogflow`.

Comment: No hay problema. En el flujo de diálogo cada intento reconoce las respuestas del usuario y permite hacer nuevas preguntas. Hay un buen video corto que te permite descubrir Dialogflow [aquí](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/video?hl=es) si quieres. Con el siguiente entiendes lo principal en cuatro minutos.

Comment: Me refería que no veo ninguna función `intent1Handler` en el ejemplo que pusiste.

Comment: ¡Sí! Los videos muestran cuáles son las intenciones. Gracias a la GUI de Dialogflow puedes seleccionar algunas respuestas predeterminadas a tu intención. Cuando quieres saber lo que devuelve la intención1, por ejemplo, tienes que crear una función en el editor de scripts, mapear la intención a una función con `intentMap.set('answer1', answer1Handler);` y declarar dentro de esa función lo que hará la respuesta a mi intención (en nuestro caso devolver la pregunta y las respuestas a la primera pregunta).

Comment: Entonces, ¿cómo puedo crear para cada pregunta una función que contenga una tarjeta con esa pregunta y esas respuestas? O, alternativamente, acceder a cada pregunta y a sus respuestas y colocarlas en funciones de tipo `IntentXHandler(agente)` que habría creado a mano?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica tienes un *edit* en la respuesta. Espero que sea lo que preguntabas.

Comment: ¡Suena genial! ¡Voy a intentarlo tan pronto como llegue a casa! ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Si pudiera enseñarle el Dialogflow, sería un placer!

Comment: Bueno, mi *stack* se aleja un poco de este tipo de librerías... Pero siempre hay que aprender de todo, claro. Espero que te sirviera.